# Run a code on server side several times and use results on html render

Tags: python, django

I want to run a code which does web scraping and want result to be rendered on html page. On each user request, code in my view function generates data and shows results on page.

Everything works fine but I suspect that this is the wrong way to implement my task. If many users will continuously request the page it will lead to server overload from which I am web scraping.

```
def my_function(request):
    url = 'https://www.some_url.com'
    source_code = requests.get(url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
    result = []
    for link in soup.find_all('div', {'id': 'some_id'}):
        for link_inside in link.find_all('span', {'class': 'some_text'}):
            a = link_inside.text.strip()
            result.append(a)
    context = {'result': result}
    return render(request, 'myweb.html', context)
```

is it possible to run the code on server side, say 12 times in a day, so I can use those results on rendering. 
1) I don't want to keep or save results on my database
2) If I need to keep results on my database is it possible to erase each time and keep updated.

Answer (score 0):

you can cache the data on your server memory with expiration time e.g. 1 hour

so if one user visits your website it caches that results and serves the cached results to other users instead of scraping the web each time a user visits the website

here's some tutorial for that:

[Django Caching for Beginners](https://wsvincent.com/django-caching-for-beginners/)

[Caching in Django With Redis](https://realpython.com/caching-in-django-with-redis/)

and for further reading you can use django's offical docs:

[Django’s cache framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/cache/)